# Error installing Postgres Gem using Chef

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra, chef-solo

I am building a Vagrant configuration (for Nginx, PHP, and Postgres) with Chef Solo, using the [databox](https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/databox) cookbook to create databases in Postgresql during provisioning.  I kept getting the error below, which I traced to `databox::postgresql`'s eventual call (via `database::paostgresql`) call to the `postgresql::ruby` recipe.  I tried running `postgresql::ruby` directly in my run list, and it produces the same error.

Logging into the VM and running `sudo /opt/ruby/bin/gem install pg` works, and the rerunning `vagrant provision` works too.  However, as I understand it, the whole point of the `postgresql::ruby` task is that it installs this gem!

Here is the output from a Chef run that runs *only* this recipe (edited slightly for readability):

```
Running chef-solo...
[2014-07-23T19:33:52+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2014-07-23T19:33:52+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.12.8 ***
[2014-07-23T19:33:52+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 1627
[2014-07-23T19:33:53+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["postgresql::ruby"] from CLI options
[2014-07-23T19:33:53+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[postgresql::ruby]]
[2014-07-23T19:33:53+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [postgresql::ruby]
[2014-07-23T19:33:53+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for vm
[2014-07-23T19:33:53+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2014-07-23T19:33:53+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2014-07-23T19:33:57+00:00] INFO: execute[apt-get update] ran successfully
[2014-07-23T19:34:09+00:00] INFO: package[ncurses-dev] is a virtual package, actually acting on package[libncurses5-dev]

================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'chef_gem[pg]'
================================================================================


LoadError
---------
cannot load such file -- pg


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/postgresql/recipes/ruby.rb:25:in `from_file'



Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/postgresql/recipes/ruby.rb

 58:     chef_gem "pg"
 59:   rescue Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError => e



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/postgresql/recipes/ruby.rb:58:in `rescue in from_file'

chef_gem("pg") do
  provider Chef::Provider::Package::Rubygems
  action :install
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  guard_interpreter :default
  package_name "pg"
  version "0.17.1"
  cookbook_name :postgresql
  recipe_name "ruby"
end


================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/postgresql/recipes/ruby.rb
================================================================================

LoadError
---------
chef_gem[pg] (postgresql::ruby line 58) had an error: LoadError: cannot load such file -- pg


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/postgresql/recipes/ruby.rb:25:in `from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/postgresql/recipes/ruby.rb:

 18:  # limitations under the License.
 19:  #
 20:
 21:  # Load the pgdgrepo_rpm_info method from libraries/default.rb
 22:  ::Chef::Recipe.send(:include, Opscode::PostgresqlHelpers)
 23:
 24:  begin
 25>>   require 'pg'
 26:  rescue LoadError
 27:
 28:    if platform_family?('ubuntu', 'debian')
 29:      e = execute 'apt-get update' do
 30:        action :nothing
 31:      end
 32:      e.run_action(:run) unless ::File.exists?('/var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp')
 33:    end
 34:


[2014-07-23T19:34:29+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-07-23T19:34:29+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-07-23T19:34:29+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-07-23T19:34:29+00:00] ERROR: chef_gem[pg] (postgresql::ruby line 58) had an error: LoadError: cannot load such file -- pg
[2014-07-23T19:34:29+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)

Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

I'm not doing anything unusual in this failing run - the VM is a stock Vagrant Ubuntu 14.04 x64 image built with Packer - and the only thing Packer did to the image is installing Chef and the VirtualBox extensions.

Any idea what's going on here?  I don't see anyone else complaining about this - am I doing something wrong or is no one else using this recipe?

Chef is version 11.12.8.

A complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) can be found [here](https://github.com/kohenkatz/chef-postgresql-SSCCE)

---

<sup>I also posted this as an issue on the [postgresql cookbook](https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/postgresql/issues/166) itself, but I figured it might get more exposure here.</sup>

Comment: Did you read the big note about the `ruby` recipe? Are you including it in your `run_list`? https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/postgresql#ruby

Comment: @sethvargo Yes, I read it, but the issue linked there does not describe the problem I am having.  It describes a different error.  As far as the `run_list`, I already stated in the question that this happens when I include `postgresql::ruby` or when I include any other recipe that includes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this issue only happens when Chef is installed as a gem, as far as I can tell.

I switched from using the Chef Gem to using Omnibus, and I was able to get it working correctly.